# Select where timestamp is in the current hour

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a cronjob that runs hourly, checks the database for a timestamp field that is in the current hour.

i.e. if the script runs at 13:00, and there's a timestamp field with 13:45 it will find it.

At the moment, I'm thinking of getting all timestamps with the current date, then getting the first 2 characters from the time and comparing it to the current time, but I was hoping there was more of a built in way to do this?

Comment: @Dagon you should put your answer back, it worked fine. There are multiple days, but I've just put the following in after your WHERE clause: 
AND DATE(`my_time_field`) = CURDATE()

Comment: The guy deleted his answer and I don't know how to contact him. The following query has resolved my question: SELECT field FROM table WHERE HOUR(field) = HOUR(NOW()) AND DATE(field) = CURDATE()

Comment: its back, when Gordon Linoff posts on sql i accept his mastery and flee.

Comment: @Dagon his query resulted in errors for me, instead of debugging his, yours worked with only a slight modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as its tagged mysql i can only guess a SQL query so:

```
SELECT foo from bar WHERE HOUR(your_time_field) = HOUR(CURTIME()) AND DATE(field) = CURDATE()
```

Mysql functions:

- HOUR = returns the hour from a date
- NOW() returns the current date with time CURDATE()current date no time

Comment: good point, it has to be a guess based on so little information.

Comment: You're slurring your words. Have you been drinking?

Comment: im in the hotel bar as we speak - hick

Comment: As there are multiple days, this query suffices with a slight modification.
SELECT field FROM table WHERE HOUR(field) = HOUR(NOW()) AND DATE(field) = CURDATE()

Comment: @Matt yup, i gave up editing - sorry will add that in for future finders

Comment: shouldn't be hour(curtime()) instead of hour(curdate()) ?

Answer (score 1):

The following looks a bit complicated, but it is actually a good way to do this:

```
where field >= FROM_UNIXTIME(floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) / (60 * 60))) and
      field < date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) / (60 * 60))), interval 1 hour)
```

What the complicated expressions are doing is finding the beginning of the current and the next hour.  The advantage to this approach is that it can take advantage of an index on `field`, if one is available.  That prevents a full table scan for getting the more recent data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$from = '2015-05-14 13:00:00';
$to = '2015-05-14 13:59:59';
. . .
"select * from users where created_at between $from and $to"
```

You should ignore all the operations with "created_at", like "hour(created_at)" because it will significantly slow down execution of the query as the engine will have to apply this operation for all the records in a loop. Also if you have an index, it more likely will be ignored.

For example, you can get records for the current hour using this way:

```
select * from users where created_at between date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

MySQL is smart enough to calculate 2 values for "between" only once; also "created_at" it is free from any functional wrappers, so if this field is indexed, the index will be used.